# nginx rewrite rule - seems to redirect instead of showing contents?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to get this rewrite rule to work:

```
rewrite ^/booking/(.*)/([0-9]+).ics$ /cgi-bin/links/booking/ical.cgi?room_id=$2&who=$1 last;
```

the **ical.cgi** script simply prints out the contents of the ical for that user. The script is pretty simple in how it outputs. First we print out the header:

```
print $IN->header( 'text/calendar' );
```

...and then just print out the iCal values. This works fine on our old server (with Apache), but for some reason I get this happening on our new nginx server:

[image]

Then if you download it, the file gets saved as `ical.cgi` , instead of `foo.ics`.

What am I doing wrong?

FWIW, this is what I have set in the main location block for .cgi scripts:

```
   location ~ \.cgi$ {
       gzip off;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181;
   }
```

The scripts actually work fine (the downloaded file IS what I'm expecting the contents to be - but the issue is that it gets written as the ical.cgi filename, instead of foo.ics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't going to mark this as an answer, but the system seems to want me to put an answer - so:

**UPDATE FIXED:** Eugh, it's one of those days! The problem was that I have this in my config:

```
  location ~ ^/cgi-bin/links/booking/ {
    rewrite (.*) https://$host$1 last;
  }
```

And the requested ical URL was:

http://www.example.org/booking/andy1/226.ics

So what it was doing, is redirecting to the https first, and that was what broke it. Doh! I will leave this post here, just in case it helps someone else ;) (even though I'm a bit embaressed by the boo-boo!)

I fixed it by doing:

```
  location ~ ^/cgi-bin/links/booking/ical.cgi {
      # do nothing!
  }

  location ~ ^/cgi-bin/links/booking/ {
      rewrite (.*)\.cgi https://$host$1.cgi last;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly stupid question, but have you enabled a CGI processing module in nginx?  If not, the behaviour you're seeing is what I'd expect (treats it as a file to be downloaded).

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah we have a reverse proxy setup for cgi (going to apache2). I've updated my question above. It's just really odd, as the other rules I have work fine (where they preserve the URL the user is on, but show the content outputted from the cgi script)

Comment: Ah man, now I feel stupid! I was using the http:// url, but then had a rule that would pull all the /booking/ locations into https - so what it was doing is processing: `rewrite (.*) https://$host$1 last;` ... thus breaking it! duh